# Can I set the color depth while capturing the webcam image using OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-capture

I am capturing the image using OpenCV in C++

```
firstFrame = cvQueryFrame(capture);
```

it is easy to set the width and height properties by

```
cvSetCaptureProperty( capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, WIDTH );
cvSetCaptureProperty( capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, HEIGHT );
```

I wonder if there is a way to specify the color depth as well without further processing the frame?

Comment: I don't think so.. I am just using a simple webcam. Is there an option?

Comment: I used     cvGetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FORMAT);     which returned -1. Do you know where can I find the cheat sheet for the applicable values?

Answer (score 3):

According to the [**documentation**](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-set), you should be able to do it using `CV_CAP_PROP_FORMAT` if you use the function `retrive()` to get your frame.

> CV_CAP_PROP_FORMAT Format of the Mat objects returned by retrieve() .

However, notice also that:

> When querying a property that is not supported by the backend used by
>   the VideoCapture class, value 0 is returned.

Answer (score 1):

Have forked a seperate branch on github, with changes to videoio to support custom streams & formats.

Git hub repo link

https://github.com/shawndfernandes/opencv

Added support for custom stream & depth for opencv capture, reverts to default opencv values if not set.

Set via VideoWriter::set method

CV_CAP_PROP_DEPTH

matrix_depth =   8,16 //* for 8U and 16 for 16U depth

CV_CAP_PROP_STREAM

stream_format  = 1,2,3,4,5…12;  //choose the raw camera stream via V4L

"BGR24"   1:

"YVU420"  2:

"YUV411P"  3:

"MJPEG"    4:

"JPEG"     5:

"YUYV"     6:

"UYVY"     7:

"SN9C10X"  8:

"SBGGR8"   9:

"SGBRG8"   10:

"RGB24"    11:

"Y16"      12: